# Can a WCF contract use multiple callback interfaces?

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm trying something like this:

```
[ServiceContract (
    CallbackContract = typeof (CallbackContract_1),
    CallbackContract = typeof (CallbackContract_2),
    CallbackContract = typeof (CallbackContract_3))
]
public interface SomeWcfContract {
```

I know it does not work like this. Is there still a way to get a single contract use multiple callback interfaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A service contract can only designate
>   a callback contract if that contract
>   is a subinterface of all callback
>   contracts defined by the contract's
>   own base contracts.

```
interface ICallbackContract1
{...}

interface ICallbackContract2 : ICallbackContract1
{...}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallbackContract1))]
interface IMyBaseContract
{...}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallbackContract2))]
interface IMySubContract : IMyBaseContract
{...}
```

or

```
interface ICallbackContract1
{...}
interface ICallbackContract2
{...}
interface ICallbackContract3 : ICallbackContract2,ICallbackContract1
{...}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallbackContract1))]
interface IMyBaseContract1
{...}
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallbackContract2))]
interface IMyBaseContract2
{...}
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallbackContract3))]
interface IMySubContract : IMyBaseContract1,IMyBaseContract2
{...}
```

[see for more details](http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Operations/Callback-Operations/)

Comment: Ah, I thought sub-interface meant something like base interface... it's rather the opposite. Now it makes an awful lot of sense suddenly. And it fits my planned app design more than perfectly.

Comment: @garik good answer! this isn't something that is intuitive or easy to find, but it works as stated.